# Игнорирование регистра в aioram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

интересует вопрос как правильно записать в handler игнорирование регистра слова. Первая мысль сразу приходит на фильтр Text

`@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='плюшка', ignore_case=True)`

Но в данном случае он будет реагировать только если слово `плюшка` будет написан отдельным сообщением, можно этого избежать используя другую структуру

`@dp.message_handler(lambda message: 'плюшка' in message.text)`

Но в данном случае он не будет игнорировать регистр, можно конечно уже в самом коде использовать `message.text.lower()` но и в этом случае handler будет реагировать на весь текст, можно ли как-то объединить эти два handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```py
@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: "плюшка" in map(str.lower, msg.text.split()))
```

А ещё, возможно, вот так

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(text_contains="плюшка", ignore_case=True)
```